# "Too many arguments to function" error while installing php5-pdo_mysql from ports in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, php, apache-httpd, bsd-ports

I'm having a trouble while installing php5-pdo_mysql in my FreeBSD environment.
Everytime I trys to do /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql make install
the console gives me this error:

```
/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql/work/php-5.3.5/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c:
501: error: too many arguments to function 'pdo_mysql_globals.dbg->m->func_leave'

/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql/work/php-5.3.5/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c:
In function 'pdo_mysql_check_liveness':
/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql/work/php-5.3.5/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c:
519: error: too many arguments to function 'pdo_mysql_globals.dbg->m->func_leave'

/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql/work/php-5.3.5/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c:
534: error: too many arguments to function 'pdo_mysql_globals.dbg->m->func_leave'

/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql/work/php-5.3.5/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c: 
In function 'pdo_mysql_handle_factory':

/usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql/work/php-5.3.5/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c:
763: error: too many arguments to function 'pdo_mysql_globals.dbg->m->func_leave'

*** Error code 1
1 error
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql.
```

My php version is 5.3.3 and pear 1.9.1.
I tried to upgrade port tree of php5 to 5.3.5 but it failed. Saying I have to update apache22 first, but then updating apache22 also failed.
What should I do now?

Comment: Try this first: `cd /usr/ports && make clean`, then `cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portsnap && make install clean`, then `portsnap fetch update`, then try to upgrade apache.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to update apache22 and php5.3.5. although /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portsnap && make install clean gave me this error:"portsnap-1.1 is now contained in the base system". but I did portsnap fetch update anyway then updated apache22 and php5 with make deinstall make reinstall. However now I got a different kind of error when I try to install php5-pdo_mysql.

Comment: I just did /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql && make deinstall and make reinstall and it worked!! thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Combining the pieces left in comments by [Yasir Arsanukaev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3226/yasir-arsanukaev) and [user3927](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3927/user3927)*</sub>

First, try

```
cd /usr/ports && make clean
cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portsnap && make install clean
portsnap fetch update
```

Then maybe upgrade Apache and PHP5 with `make deinstall reinstall`.

Finally, reinstall `php5-pdo_mysql` with

```
cd /usr/ports/databases/php5-pdo_mysql && make deinstall reinstall
```